# Detect posedge for sync signal [Without using @posedge signal]

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to detect the posedge of a synchronous signal, but I don't know how to implement it relative to the clock [Without using `@posedge signal`].
Can I implement it like `@(posedge clk iff -----`)?

Comment: If you post a link to what you have read  regarding this, then the community is able to provide clarification on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronous design should provide and sample signals on same clock edge.

To find a positive edge (low to high transition), you have to save signal previous value, so you can find positive edge when current value is 1, but previous value is 0.

Example:

```
logic sig_prev;
logic positive_edge_detected;


always @(posedge clk)
begin
  sig_prev <= sig;
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
  positive_edge_detected = 0;
  if((sig == 1) && (sig_prev==0)) begin
    positive_edge_detected = 1;
  end
end
```

For good design you should implement an asynchronous reset too.